# Angular ui-select within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-select

I'm using ui-select within an ng-repeat to create a select box for each item over a collection. However, when I select a node ID in any of the individual select boxes it ends up getting selected in *all* of them. How can I configure the `{{$select.selected.id}}` part such that only the current choice select box gets updated? Here is the relevant code:

```
<div style="float:left; width:160px;" ng-repeat="choice in choices">
<div class="input-group">
    <ui-select ng-model="node.selected" theme="bootstrap" ng-disabled="disabled" reset-csearch-input="true" style="width:50px; float:left">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="{{choice.to_node_id}}">{{$select.selected.id}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="node in nodes | filter: $select.search">
            <div ng-bind-html="node.id | highlight: $select.search" ng-click="updateChoiceLink(choice, node)"></div>
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
</div>
```

Comment: if you define separate ng-model values for each of the selects this can be solved.If you provide a plunker i can demonstrate it

Comment: I changed ng-model to `"choice.selected"` and it works now :) Thanks a bunch!

Comment: post how you solved it and accept it as answer so incase someone got the same problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by binding the model to `choice.selected`as opposed to `node.selected`. This way each select box has a unique ng-model based on the choice.

Comment: Hey, can you post your controller code? i am struck with same problem.

Comment: <ui-select multiple n-d="{{columnsTagObj.displayColumns[colValues.tag]}}" ng-model="columnsTagObj.displayColumns[colValues.tag]"   theme="selectize"  ng-disabled="disabled"  reset-search-input="false"  required>
 <ui-select-match>{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
<ui-select-choices refresh="getDrugNameList($select.search)" refresh-delay="0" repeat="item in Druglist | filter:$select.search">
                                     {{item}}
                                 </ui-select-choices>
                             </ui-select>

Comment: I am using ng-repeat to create two  input box of ui-select but the first one is showing blank and second one is showing both first and second value even the ng-model is different for each